# Upload website in HTML 5

Tags: html, dns

1. How can I upload my website
2. How can I choose an URL
3. How to have many pages in your website which are linked

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to have some hosting with public IP.
2. You need to buy domain name from some provider,
3. Don't understand the question...

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to find some hosting, there are a lot of free hostings if you only do your website for fun/school project like [cba](https://www.cba.pl/en) (free hostings can add ad to your website) etc. Then you will have to use some kind of ftp client to connect to your website server and upload your website files.
2. When creating account on those websites they will ask you to chouse yor domain name [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biqgd.png).
3. Coud you explain?

Comment: 3. I mean like www.website.com and www.website.com/text. Do I have to create more html files or a new page or what.